# ODOO 'function' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Tags: python-2.7, odoo-8, odoo-9

I got problem to get the value of list :

```
def _get_state(self, cr, uid, context=None):
    idemployee = _default_employee(self, cr, uid, context=None)
    # sql = " SELECT id, sequence, name FROM wf_state ORDER BY sequence "
    sql = " SELECT C.id AS id, C.sequence, C.name, member_id, name_related AS employee_name, \
                   B.name AS group_name, C.name AS state_name FROM wf_group_member A \
           LEFT JOIN wf_group B ON B.id = A.group_id \
           LEFT JOIN wf_process BB ON BB.id = B.process_id\
           LEFT JOIN wf_state C ON C.group_id = B.id \
           LEFT JOIN hr_employee D ON D.id = A.member_id \
           WHERE LOWER(code) = 'ca' AND member_id = %s ORDER BY sequence "
    res = []
    cr.execute(sql, [(idemployee)])
    ardata = cr.fetchall()
    for data in ardata:
        # res.append((data[1], data[2]))
        res.append((data[1], data[2]))
    return res

array_state = _get_state

class cashadvance(osv.osv):
    _name = 'ga.cashadvance'
    _columns = {
        'state' : fields.selection(array_state, 'Status', readonly=True, required=True),
    }

_defaults={
        'state' : array_state[0][0],
    }
```

error in log is :
'state' : array_state[0][0],
TypeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'getitem_'

Please help me on this

Comment: please try and close this question by marking an answer or making further comments if any of the answers below didn't address your question properly, if you don't provide feedback the question remains open and marking an answer is a way of saying thank you to whoever answered your question and that's apparently @kenly

Comment: ok, thanks for remind me :)

Comment: That's not all, under the upvote and downvote arrows you'll see a grey check sign, click on that to mark the answer as the correct one....it'll turn green when you do that...and after that delete your answer you posted it should be a comment instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `_defaults` to:

```
_defaults={
    'state' : lambda self, cr, uid, context: array_state(self, cr, uid, context)[0][0],
   }
```

you must make sure that the result is not empty.

Comment: @yogakumboro Feel free to accept the answer or upvote it.

Answer (score 0):

You inteded to call the `_get_state` function. You should do:

```
array_state = _get_state(args...)
```

You omitted the parenthesis, and thus you assigned the function object itself into array_state, instead of assigning the returned value from `_get_state`.

Then you actually try to put an index on the function object, which of course, doesn't support this kind of operation. Objects that support indexing - like the object returned from `_get_state` - have a method called `__getitem__`.

Comment: I've tried to call _get_state function with :

array_state = _get_state(self, cr, uid, context=None)

but show this error :

array_state = _get_state(self, cr, uid, context=None)
NameError: name 'self' is not defined